# WebRTC conncet with SFU server failed using Lite ICE

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sdp, ice

I'm trying to connect my web client with my SFU server. And the SFU server implements lite ICE.
Here's the SDP sent by my web client:

```
v=0
o=- 1250414714658974016 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio
a=msid-semantic: WMS RNSq70GfxaWKMGzvpJcEAqpMw9dnbB5U1N9a
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:h1kO
a=ice-pwd:aXsis+1NfXMwOmc5ICjAH0NC
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 DA:6F:29:E4:6B:89:76:F9:F1:BD:E0:75:BB:EB:D2:54:0B:C8:83:54:BA:C4:E2:67:E1:FF:38:DD:D2:17:8C:74
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:3584188035 cname:Vx+7hyzjBBd0353j
a=ssrc:3584188035 msid:RNSq70GfxaWKMGzvpJcEAqpMw9dnbB5U1N9a 4428e230-46d2-4718-8f2b-05e0e05c084b
a=ssrc:3584188035 mslabel:RNSq70GfxaWKMGzvpJcEAqpMw9dnbB5U1N9a
a=ssrc:3584188035 label:4428e230-46d2-4718-8f2b-05e0e05c084b
```

Here's the SDP sent by my SFU server:

```
v=0
o=- 7437866493835506893 2 IN IP4 10.1.29.248
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio
a=msid-semantic: WMS xzlDAum3wM3zhq0yidoOIw3xda3W45AWM0jd
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 10.1.29.248
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 10.1.29.248
a=candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2122260223 10.1.29.248 60197 typ host
a=ice-ufrag:0ewh
a=ice-pwd:610Q94mNcZLoL5uVoSZyXKuW
a=ice-options:trickle
a=ice-lite
a=end-of-candidates
a=fingerprint:sha-256 48:53:40:64:CF:F8:8A:69:F8:CD:66:E0:A6:70:57:07:2A:DC:51:53:26:5C:BD:1A:F1:FD:05:B1:40:9F:63:D9
a=setup:active
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:3676579219 cname:2KRN6J2bznW2MyqZ
a=ssrc:3676579219 msid:xzlDAum3wM3zhq0yidoOIw3xda3W45AWM0jd 80ff593f-401e-4928-ad74-28e34923d9ad
a=ssrc:3676579219 mslabel:xzlDAum3wM3zhq0yidoOIw3xda3W45AWM0jd
a=ssrc:3676579219 label:80ff593f-401e-4928-ad74-28e34923d9ad
```

The pcap file captured by WireShark shows that SFU server send a **BINDING SUCCESS** response.
[image]
But the connectionState and iceConnectionState of my **RTCPeerConnection** is always "failed".

[image]

I have checked the remoteDescription.sdp of my RTCPeerConnection object.
The line `a=ice-lite` disappeared.
[image]

What's the problem? Is the SDP generated by my SFU server wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`ice-lite` is a session-level attribute (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5245#section-15.3) and will only be understood before any `m=` lines in the SDP. Moving the line a bit should make it show up in the remoteDescription.sdp.

This should also (if your SFU is a lite peer) make the connection work -- otherwise the browser will expect binding requests.

Comment: That works! Thank you! BTW, is there any way for web client to send a STUN BINDING request with REALM attribute? There is no REALM attribute in STUN BINDING request by default

Comment: there is not, REALM is a TURN concept and not a STUN one.

Comment: Now the "ice-lite" works. But `pc.iceConnectionState` changes to `disconnected`. The browser truly received `BINDING SUCCESS` response with `MAPPED-ADDRESS` and `MESSAGE-INTEGRITY` attribute. Maybe there are some mistakes?